# injector module error in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with using a module in my angular app:

I installed [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) with 
`bower install async`

I added the script to `index.html` :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ext/async/lib/async.js"></script>
```

I added `"async": "0.9.0"` to `bower.json`

Then, i injected the module in my app :

`var app = angular.module('app', ['async',...])`

And i get the following error :

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app
>   due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module async
>   due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'async' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module nam......1)

Answer (score 0):

I found out i didn't have to inject `async` to my app nor to give it to my controller .. since it was not built for angular.
What is needed is to add the script tag to `index.html`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ext/async/lib/async.js"></script>`

and that's all